# How can I run a file in VSCode in the Command Prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I do a lot of Python development and I need my files to open directly in Command Prompt when I run them. Is there a way I can set up VSCode to run the current file in Command Prompt instead of the integrated terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? The integrated terminal is an embedded command prompt

Comment: @Ayush Gundawar -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code, its internal terminal is an integrated terminal from the system, and for Windows systems, it uses the Powershell terminal by default.

For use the "cmd" terminal inside VS Code, we can use the settings in "settings.json":

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```

[image]

If you want to run code outside of VS Code, you can use it in "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)":

```
"console": "externalTerminal",
```

Then click `F5` to debug the code:

[image]

Reference: [Integrated Terminal in VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Find where your program is saved either by opening the save position in visual studio code or you can try the default save position here C:\users{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code (You may have changed this) In this directory then find your program you want to run if you made a virtual environment make sure to enable it with `cd venv/Scripts/activate.bat` (Windows) or `. venv/bin/activate` (Linux) these will open your venv then to actually run your program use `python <FileName>.py`
Your installations may be slightly different from the standard so please ask if you have any difficulty.

Comment: You don't need to open a virtual environment if you are not using any external packages from pip or other .whl